# Using the 'make' plugin for software which does not specify an 'install' target

Tags: snap

I thought I'd try my hand at snapping something, and picked `sl` as the place to start, because a) it's fairly simple, and b) it's the best thing in the world ever. [This](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22683322/) is my snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: sl
version: "1.0"
summary: SL(1) - Cure your bad habit of mistyping
description: SL (Steam Locomotive) runs across your terminal when you type "sl" as you meant to type "ls". It's just a joke command, and not useful at all.
confinement: strict

apps:
  sl:
    command: sl

parts:
  sl:
    plugin: make
    source: https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl.git
    source-type: git
    source-branch: master
    build-packages:
      - libncurses5-dev
```

However, when I run snapcraft, I get [the following error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22683252/):

```
$ snapcraft 
Preparing to pull sl 
Pulling sl 
Cloning into '/home/darren/Scratch/snapls/parts/sl/src'...
remote: Counting objects: 11, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 11 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Preparing to build sl 
Building sl 
make -j4
gcc -O -o sl sl.c -lncurses
make install DESTDIR=/home/darren/Scratch/snapls/parts/sl/install
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop.
Command '['/bin/sh', '/tmp/tmpyus7efkq', 'make', 'install', 'DESTDIR=/home/darren/Scratch/snapls/parts/sl/install']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did nothing wrong. If you take a look at the [the Makefile](https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/blob/master/Makefile), you can see that it does not define at all, how and where to install the resulting binary.

I played around with the `make` plugin's `make-parameters` option, but couldn't get it to ignore the missing `install` target. To fix this there are two options:

1. Post a PR for https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl where you add an `install` target and use your fork for building in the meantime.
2. Add a [custom plugin](http://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/plugins) which just runs `make` and not `make install`.

Comment: https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl/pull/17 adds an install target. You could use that as a basis and maybe provide it in a separate PR which maybe has the chance to get merged a bit more quickly.

Comment: Thanks dholbach, I'll look into that. Meanwhile, I've been informed that there is a pull request that could solve this at https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/pull/715 

Apparently, it adds the option to specify a list of artifacts, and if the list of artifacts is there, it copies them to installdir instead of running make install.

Comment: Ooooh, nice! I wasn't aware of that. :-)